# Why does my page not display correctly in Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I created a simple page with a series of divs. In all of the modern browsers, it appears fine, but in Internet Explorer 6, it falls apart. I have no idea what is causing it to happen.

You can view the page here: [IE 6 Test Page](http://idea-palette.com/ie6test/)

If you have IE6 installed, I included the Firebug Lite JS file on the page, so just click the firebug icon in the bottom right corner to inspect an element.

Here's a screenshot using Browserlab to view the page in Firefox and IE6: [Comparison Screenshot](http://idea-palette.com/ie6test/comparison.jpg)

[image: Comparison of PAge using Firefox and IE6]

The 3rd div named 'content'(With the Manager Email field) moves everything to the right forcing the next div to the next line. Also, none of the row div's reach all the way across as they should(see [Comparison Screenshot](http://idea-palette.com/ie6test/comparison.jpg))

I did some research and have found that there is some problems in IE6 using floats which I use here, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Why does my page not display correctly in Internet Explorer 6? And better yet, how can I fix it? :)

Comment: If all else fails, a dirty but safe trick would be to use a table. But this can be fixed for IE6 without, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the third div isn't clearing the float properly. Perhaps give each of the `row` divs the style `clear: both`

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* need to support IE6? Even Microsoft is [fighting it](http://ie6countdown.com) nowadays and the market share is starting to be irrelevant except for China.

Comment: I totally agree with you and in any other case, I most likely would just abandon this fight, but in this case it is for a corporate client and in a user-study from an employee there, they were using IE6. I have no way of knowing how many more at that company use IE6 on their computers, so I don't think it would be wise for me to risk that.

Comment: [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) claims to have some IE6 fixes, maybe you should have a look at it. And my deepest sympathy... ;)

Comment: Yeah, there are some very large corporations *still* using IE6. I know from experience! :(:(:(

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between "not working in IE6" and "not looking perfect in IE6".

As has already been said, IE6's market share is low and continuing to fall -- it's below 2% in most of the developed world (see http://gs.statcounter.com/ for country-by-country stats).

Given those stats, I would say that if the page is *usable* in IE6 then your work is done. IE6 users are by now used to web pages looking bad. Many popular sites don't work at all in their browser, so one with a few layout glitches won't phase them at all. They'll still use the site.

If it is actually broken to the point of not being usable then it's a different story; in that case, you'd need to consider how important those few IE6 users are to you vs the time it'll take to do the work, and fix it accordingly, but that doesn't seen to be case here: the page seems to work. It looks a bit naff, but it works.